# Why is my image not changing every 1 second by the onTick() method?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

### **PROBLEM: The images change, but not in the appropriate time.**

Hereby the `CountDownTimer` class reference:

> ### **CountDownTimer**
>
> *Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way.*
>
> **Public Constructors**
>
> `CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)`
>
> `millisInFuture`  *The number of millis in the future from the call to start() until the countdown is done and onFinish() is called*.
>
> `countDownInterval`   *The interval along the way to receive onTick(long) callbacks*.
>
> Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Assuming that I have the following two images:

- [image]
- [image]

And I want to change between them every 1 second,

what am I doing wrong here? Can someone give me a direction?

```
    blinkingAlarm = new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

    boolean switchImage = false;

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        if(!switchImage)
        {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }
        else if(switchImage)
        {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);           
        }

        // Flip
        switchImage = (!switchImage);

    }


    @Override
    public void onFinish() {    

        // Loop
        blinkingAlarm.start();
    }
};
```

The method is being called by

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {

        case R.id.button1:  
            blinkingAlarm.start();
        break;

        }

}
```

Comment: did you start `blinkingAlarm` ?

Comment: From what I am seeing you are calling start only in onFinish()

Comment: This timer is being started by a `onClick` event. It executes, but doesn't change the images by 1 second delay.

Comment: Post the code of the onClick event then.

Comment: my hard guess is that 1000,1000 as parameters, only onFinish is invoked

Comment: Setting it to 3000,1000 as parameters for example seems to make no difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use handler and postDelayed instead CountDownTimer.
In your class add this variables:

```
private boolean switchImage = false;
private Handler handler;
```

Then use this code:

```
handler = new Handler();

Runnable changeImage = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!switchImage){
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
                switchImage = true;
            } else {
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
                switchImage = false;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 1000);
```